# Three.js Blender Import Black Textures

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

im currently trying to update individual textures based on cursor position on imported JSON model. Below is the import code for the JSON model

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('slicedNew.json', function(geometry, materials) {
        console.log(materials);
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ));
        mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = 8;
        mesh.translation = THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
        scene.add(mesh);
        console.log('IMPORTED OBJECT: ', mesh);

    });
```

Below is raycaster code for when the cursor is over a particular material

```
     switch(intersects[0].face.materialIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    console.log('0 material index');
                    intersects[0].object.material.needsUpdate = true;

                    intersects[0].object.material.materials[0] =   new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                            map: crate
                        });
                    break;
```

Anytime I hover over a certain side of the shape the texture is loaded but it is always black, even initialise the model to use the texture it still appears as black, yet I can load in a simple cube and map the image as a texture to this shape with no issues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your textures have size that is powers of two?

Comment: I was getting that warning but I swapped to a different image and no longer get this warning anymore.